# HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error for getDate()

Tags: java, mysql, web-applications

The database has a column named  'SomeDate' of type DATE with data filled in. Why does than I got the following  error for this line?

```
java.sql.Date dbSqlDate = results.getDate("SomeDate");
```

> HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
>
> Type Exception Report
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that
>   prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Exception java.lang.NullPointerException
>     com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:2022)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:1985)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:2041)
>     dbHelpers.UpdateQuery.doUpdate(UpdateQueryForChangeStock.java:105)
>     controllers.UpdateServlet.doPost(UpdateForChangeStockServlet.java:45)
>     controllers.UpdateServlet.doGet(UpdateForChangeStockServlet.java:34)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server
>   logs.

Why it point to null? as I said there is data.

Comment: share complete error message plz

Comment: @ErnestKiwele No,  Why it point to null? as I said there is data.

Comment: can you show us the full error please?

Comment: @student So does that mean `results` is not the variable holding the result set?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele You were right the results did get null (holding 0 variable in a set)...thanks!!!